# Create android studio project from ssh Git (bitbucket) link

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I was given a ssh link to a bitbucket repo so I can work on the project. The link someone gave me was something like ssh://git@bitbucket.CompanyName.tools/sp/company-project.git.

How would I create an android studio project, linked to this repo, to work on this project and view the files? I have never worked with git so this is all new.
I do not see the repo in my main bitbucket account if it makes any difference or not

Comment: For easiest way u can use SourceTree Software to work with repository.

Comment: With the greatest respect, have you done a web search for "android studio git plugin"? I've not used it, but there seems to be plenty written about it. If you tried following instructions that haven't worked, perhaps post what you tried and what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio go to:

```
File->New->Project from Version Control->Git
```

then in the dialog enter the link provided in your question `ssh://git@bitbucket.CompanyName.tools/sp/company-project.git`

Answer (score 3):

1. Create clone of the given repo by entering below command in your terminal :

> git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.CompanyName.tools/sp/company-project.git

2. After cloning checkout to new branch by :

> git checkout -b newBranchName

3. Last step, go in your `Android Studio`, and Import the folder where you have clone the given repo.

Answer (score 1):

`File`>`New`>`Project From Version Control`>`Git` is what you need